# PHP function is automatically called when page loads, instead of being called through onclick event

Tags: php, javascript, session, web-applications, post

I'm trying to redirect users of a web page to one of two different pages, depending on which of two buttons they click. My approach was to link each onclick event to a javascript function, which would in turn call a php function which uses the header() function to redirect to the appropriate page. Unfortunately, the latter of the two php functions, namely insertIntoTable(), is being called automatically each time the page loads and redirecting, without giving the user a chance to even look at the page with the buttons. I'm wondering if this is an artifact of way PHP is expanded? I don't really understand, becauseit seems like the wrapping javascript function shouldn't be called until the onclick event listener does so, and the php functions shouldn't be called until on the the javascript functions *linked* to onclick do so. Here is the code...

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function createATable()
            {
                <?php createATable(); ?>
            }

            function insertIntoTable()
            {
                <?php insertIntoTable(); ?>
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            // Define our redirection functions for button click events
            function createATable()
            {
                header("Location: http://codd.edu/Project2/createtable.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>");*/
            }
            function insertIntoTable()
            {
                header("Location: http://codd.edu/Project2/insertintotable.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>");*/
            }

            // Set session variables so that we don't need to worry about whether
            // we're coming from sign in or registration - if $Session['user_name'] 
            // isn't set, we know were coming from the sign in
            if (!$_SESSION['user_name'])
            {
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['nametextbox'];
                $_SESSION['user_psswd'] = $_POST['psswdtextbox'];
                echo "<br />setting session variables";
            }
            echo "<br />Not setting session variables";

            // If we aren't setting the session variables, then we are coming from the 
            // registration page, and therefore know that this isn't an admin account
            $_SESSION['is_admin'] = "false";

            // Connect to database
            $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "601", "23");
                or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

            // Open database
            mysql_select_db("601", $conn) 
                or die('Could not find database: ' . mysql_error());

            // Get USER tuples, if any
            $user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE name='$_SESSION[user_name]' AND password='$_SESSION[user_psswd]'");

            // If there are no entries for this SELECT command, we cannot 
            // allow the user to log in 
            $num_user = mysql_num_rows($user);
            if ($num_user < 1) 
            {
                $_SESSION['is_user'] = "false";
                header("Location: http://codd.edu/Project2/login.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>");
                exit;
            } 
            else 
            {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = SID;
                $_SESSION['is_user'] = "true";
                echo "Welcome ", $_SESSION['user_name'], "!";
                echo "<br />User ID: " . $_SESSION['user_id'];
                echo "<br /> User Password: " . $_SESSION['user_psswd'];
                echo "Is valid user? " . $_SESSION['is_user'];
                session_destroy();

                echo "<button name='createtable' onclick='createATable()'>Create a Table</button>";
                echo "<br /><button name='insert' onclick='insertIntoTable()'>Insert into Table</button>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason why `createATable()` shouldn't be called anytime the page is loaded. PHP is evaluated before javascript and on a different environment. Moreover, PHP allows you do define/declare a function after you call it, that is exactly what you're doing.

Pretend to be the PHP interpreter: it has no idea of what javascript is. You can even wrap the `<?php createATable(); ?>` line with `yadayadayada ... qweryasdasd` before and after it, and it will run.

Please, read this and see if it helps: http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/923111/Client-side-Versus-Server-side-Coding---Part-1.htm

PS.: this is not related to your question, but please take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks gd1, makes total sense.

Comment: So I think maybe the best thing to do is dump the php functions altogether and redirect with javascript's window.location variable and append the session ID with <?php htmlspecialchars(SID) ?> ?

Comment: Oh I'm *positive* it's vulnerable to sql injection, but the 'data' is all dummy, just trying to get the logic up and working for now.

Comment: Yes, use javascript to move to the other page. Actually you can even suppress the SID part, because session cookies are seldom rejected.

Comment: For the SQL injection is OK if you fix it, but please allow me to suggest you not to do like this (make a stub with fatal bugs and refine it later) because sometimes the flaws don't get fixed and are just left there.

Comment: If you worry about javascript being turned of and users getting stuck, you can still add a way out with the noscript tag. Don't only worry about sql injection, list all possible threats. @MassStrike

Answer (score 0):

Php runs on the server, the htnl output goes to the client.

Instead of trying to use php to redirect, use javascript or a simple a href.

Comment: Yup, I can see that now. Thanks guys.